# Web App - Application Initialization during swap when no reset occurs

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, iis-8, azure-app-service-plans

For applications needing "warming up", the [Application Initialization](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/) module is useful in the case that an IIS reset occurs on the staging slot as it swaps into production. This (an IIS reset) would typically happen if a slot setting is configured on the Web App.

**In the case of slots which DO NOT reset upon swapping, is it possible for the Application Initialization module to still initialize?** I.e. Without a reset, can Application Initialization still request from and wait for the warm up page to complete?

Answer (score 2):

After configured the applicationInitialization, the initial pages will be hit on your web application initialization(start or restart).

```
<system.webServer>
  <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
    <add initializationPage="/page.aspx" hostName="xx.xx.com" />
  </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Based on the article which you posted. If there is no configuration setting need be swapped, the web application will not be restarted. The initial pages will not be hit.

> is it possible for the Application Initialization module to still initialize?

I haven't found a way to do it and I think it is not required to do it. Since your web application is not restarted, the application states and caches are not lost.

Comment: The reason I wish to call on application initialization is because it might take a long time for warming up (30 minutes for example), which might not be sufficient time between deploying to the staging slot and swapping into production.

Comment: The application initialization job will keep doing during the swapping operation if the web app is not restart.